# String.raw output "${" and bacticks

Tags: javascript

I am using `String.raw` to hold the contents to hold a regex that contains values like `${somevalue}` in a RegExp I have.  It works except there appears to be no way to escape `${}` or backticks.
For example this doesn't work.

```
String.raw`${}`  // error
String.raw`$\{}`  // wrong output
String.raw`\${}`  // wrong output
String.raw`\``    /wrong output
```

Unfortunately the best solution I can come up with is the following.

```
String.rawer= (s)=>{return s.raw[0].replace(/\\\{/g,"{").replace(/\\`/g,'`').replace(/\\\\$/,'\\')}
```

Is there a solution that is less ugly that doesn't require defining my own function and subsequent function calls?

Comment: This is an interesting question and it displays a shortcoming of template strings but without knowing why and how you use `String.raw` and don't want to use a template function, it feels a little like a XY problem.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm confused by your comment. I have my own RegExp engine I am using just like the question states and I need ${ inside the RegExp. If you would like me to post the actual code I can but it really won't change the question. I would like to add RegExp are probably the only use case for String.raw that I can think of. My main hope was that there was a non documented rawer function that took it one step further and allowed you to escape &{. I do agree stating I don't want function calls or templates is slightly wired but I had hoped and assumed there was a standard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this looks cleaner than what you have

```js
console.log(String.raw`${"${}"}`)
```

You would have to put the `${}` inside a `${}` and put quotes around it inside. But this is an annoying issue that doesn't really have a *simple* solution to it, that I am aware of anyways.

Comment: I would argue it isn't cleaner but is another solution.